# How do I remove the space between navigation bar and dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

how do I remove that space between navigation bar and those 2 menus "Detalii" and "Administrator"?

The space created as a result of me deleting 2  from each div and instead of the dropdown moving up, it remained the same just with a blank space between it and the nav bar, as you may see in the snippet.

EDIT: The snippet doesn't show the problem, so here is  [my JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shade1337/546355j2/)

```css
.navigation {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 60px;
    border: 0px solid #E3E3E3;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 1080px;
}

    .navigation a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: antiquewhite;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 25px;
        width: 174px;
    }

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        border-style: none;
        border-color: inherit;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 0px;
        outline: none;
        color: antiquewhite;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        width: 216px;
    }

    .navigation a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4e3f3f;
    }

.dropdown-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(186,179,179);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 216px;
}

    .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: antiquewhite;
        padding: 19px 0px 20px 0px;
        text-decoration: none; 
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: inherit;
    }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #4e3f3f;
        }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
                  <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="~/Pages/Home.aspx" runat="server">Home</a>
                      </div>
                <div class="dropdown" style="width:20%; float:left">
                    <button class="dropbtn">&nbsp;&nbsp; Detalii<i class="fa fa-caret-down">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cafea.aspx" runat="server">Sortimente</a>
                        <a href="#">Cafea cu lapte</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="~/Pages/Magazin.aspx" runat="server">Magazin</a>
                    </div>
                <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="#despre" runat="server">Despre</a>
                    </div>
                <div class="dropdown" style="width:20%; float:left">
                    <button class="dropbtn" id="A1" runat="server" visible="false">Administrator</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cafea_Overview.aspx" runat="server">Management</a>
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cont/Admin.aspx" runat="server">Utilizatori</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the css for your dropdown-content div, why do you have bottom:0px? Surely for your needs you just need to use the correct value for top, which would be the total height of the navbar. In this case, 68px.

Seems too simple. Have I misunderstood something?

```css
.navigation {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 60px;
    border: 0px solid #E3E3E3;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 1080px;
}

    .navigation a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: antiquewhite;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 25px;
        width: 174px;
    }

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        border-style: none;
        border-color: inherit;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 0px;
        outline: none;
        color: antiquewhite;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        width: 216px;
    }

    .navigation a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4e3f3f;
    }

.dropdown-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(186,179,179);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 216px;
    top:68px;
}

    .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: antiquewhite;
        padding: 19px 0px 20px 0px;
        text-decoration: none; 
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: inherit;
    }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #4e3f3f;
        }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
                  <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="~/Pages/Home.aspx" runat="server">Home</a>
                      </div>
                <div class="dropdown" style="width:20%; float:left">
                    <button class="dropbtn">&nbsp;&nbsp; Detalii<i class="fa fa-caret-down">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cafea.aspx" runat="server">Sortimente</a>
                        <a href="#">Cafea cu lapte</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="~/Pages/Magazin.aspx" runat="server">Magazin</a>
                    </div>
                <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="#despre" runat="server">Despre</a>
                    </div>
                <div class="dropdown" style="width:20%; float:left">
                    <button class="dropbtn" id="A1" runat="server" visible="false">Administrator</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cafea_Overview.aspx" runat="server">Management</a>
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cont/Admin.aspx" runat="server">Utilizatori</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I don't know if it's something wrong with my VS, but I added bottom:128px and worked, it displays right beneath the menus. But thanks, your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Beat me to it. But He is right as well. He came out with the same solution as mine. This does help. Cheers. Happy Coding

```css
.navigation {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 60px;
    border: 0px solid #E3E3E3;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 1080px;
}

    .navigation a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: antiquewhite;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 25px;
        width: 174px;
    }

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        border-style: none;
        border-color: inherit;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 0px;
        outline: none;
        color: antiquewhite;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        width: 216px;
    }

    .navigation a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4e3f3f;
    }

  .dropdown-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 68px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1f1d1d;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(186,179,179);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 216px;

    .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: antiquewhite;
        padding: 19px 0px 20px 0px;
        text-decoration: none; 
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: inherit;
    }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #4e3f3f;
        }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
                  <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="~/Pages/Home.aspx" runat="server">Home</a>
                      </div>
                <div class="dropdown" style="width:20%; float:left">
                    <button class="dropbtn">&nbsp;&nbsp; Detalii<i class="fa fa-caret-down">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cafea.aspx" runat="server">Sortimente</a>
                        <a href="#">Cafea cu lapte</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="~/Pages/Magazin.aspx" runat="server">Magazin</a>
                    </div>
                <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="#despre" runat="server">Despre</a>
                    </div>
                <div class="dropdown" style="width:20%; float:left">
                    <button class="dropbtn" id="A1" runat="server" visible="false">Administrator</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cafea_Overview.aspx" runat="server">Management</a>
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cont/Admin.aspx" runat="server">Utilizatori</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try reducing the margin of the `body`.

```css
body {
   margin-top: 0;
}

.navigation {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 60px;
    border: 0px solid #E3E3E3;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 1080px;
}

    .navigation a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: antiquewhite;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 25px;
        width: 174px;
    }

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        border-style: none;
        border-color: inherit;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 0px;
        outline: none;
        color: antiquewhite;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        width: 216px;
    }

    .navigation a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4e3f3f;
    }

.dropdown-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(186,179,179);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 216px;
}

    .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: antiquewhite;
        padding: 19px 0px 20px 0px;
        text-decoration: none; 
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: inherit;
    }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #4e3f3f;
        }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
                  <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="~/Pages/Home.aspx" runat="server">Home</a>
                      </div>
                <div class="dropdown" style="width:20%; float:left">
                    <button class="dropbtn">&nbsp;&nbsp; Detalii<i class="fa fa-caret-down">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cafea.aspx" runat="server">Sortimente</a>
                        <a href="#">Cafea cu lapte</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="~/Pages/Magazin.aspx" runat="server">Magazin</a>
                    </div>
                <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="#despre" runat="server">Despre</a>
                    </div>
                <div class="dropdown" style="width:20%; float:left">
                    <button class="dropbtn" id="A1" runat="server" visible="false">Administrator</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cafea_Overview.aspx" runat="server">Management</a>
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cont/Admin.aspx" runat="server">Utilizatori</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little tweak of your code. Remove of overflow hidden, bottom and adding position relative to dropdown:

```css
.navigation {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 60px;
    border: 0px solid #E3E3E3;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 1080px;
}

    .navigation a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: antiquewhite;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 25px;
        width: 174px;
    }

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        border-style: none;
        border-color: inherit;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 0px;
        outline: none;
        color: antiquewhite;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        width: 216px;
    }

    .navigation a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4e3f3f;
    }

.dropdown-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1f1d1d;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(186,179,179);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 216px;
}

    .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: antiquewhite;
        padding: 19px 0px 20px 0px;
        text-decoration: none; 
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: inherit;
    }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #4e3f3f;
        }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
                  <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="~/Pages/Home.aspx" runat="server">Home</a>
                      </div>
                <div class="dropdown" style="width:20%; float:left">
                    <button class="dropbtn">&nbsp;&nbsp; Detalii<i class="fa fa-caret-down">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cafea.aspx" runat="server">Sortimente</a>
                        <a href="#">Cafea cu lapte</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="~/Pages/Magazin.aspx" runat="server">Magazin</a>
                    </div>
                <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                <a href="#despre" runat="server">Despre</a>
                    </div>
                <div class="dropdown" style="width:20%; float:left">
                    <button class="dropbtn" id="A1" runat="server" visible="false">Administrator</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cafea_Overview.aspx" runat="server">Management</a>
                        <a href="~/Pages/Cont/Admin.aspx" runat="server">Utilizatori</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can also use this way

```css
    .navigation {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border: 0px solid #E3E3E3;
        background-color: #1f1d1d;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        width: 1080px;
    }

        .navigation a {
            float: left;
            font-size: 25px;
            color: antiquewhite;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 18px 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
            height: 25px;
            width: 174px;
        }

    .dropdown {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

        .dropdown .dropbtn {
            border-style: none;
            border-color: inherit;
            font-size: 25px;
            margin: 0px;
            outline: none;
            color: antiquewhite;
            padding: 16px 20px;
            background-color: inherit;
            font-family: inherit;
            width: 216px;
        }

        .navigation a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: #4e3f3f;
        }

    .dropdown-content {
        overflow: hidden;
        
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #1f1d1d;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(186,179,179);
        z-index: 1;
        width: 216px;
    }

        .dropdown-content a {
            float: none;
            color: antiquewhite;
            padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
            text-decoration: none; 
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            width: inherit;
        }

            .dropdown-content a:hover {
                background-color: #4e3f3f;
            }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="navigation">
                      <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                    <a href="~/Pages/Home.aspx" runat="server">Home</a>
                          </div>
                    <div class="dropdown" style="width:20%; float:left">
                        <button class="dropbtn">&nbsp;&nbsp; Detalii<i class="fa fa-caret-down">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="~/Pages/Cafea.aspx" runat="server">Sortimente</a>
                            <a href="#">Cafea cu lapte</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                    <a href="~/Pages/Magazin.aspx" runat="server">Magazin</a>
                        </div>
                    <div style="width:20%; float:left">
                    <a href="#despre" runat="server">Despre</a>
                        </div>
                    <div class="dropdown" style="width:20%; float:left">
                        <button class="dropbtn" id="A1" runat="server" visible="false">Administrator</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="~/Pages/Cafea_Overview.aspx" runat="server">Management</a>
                            <a href="~/Pages/Cont/Admin.aspx" runat="server">Utilizatori</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```